# Pass proc/lambda in resque jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I am using `resque` gem for background tasks.
I want to pass proc as an argument to the worker. Is there a way to do that?
eg:

```
Resque.enqueue_in(3.hours, ExecuteAfterIntervalWorker, self.class.name, self.id, method_name, if: Proc.new{|e| e.enabled? })
```

Comment: At last made a method call for if condition if method present. It made it work but not happy :(

Answer (score 1):

Things you pass to resque, they must be serializable to json. And procs aren't serializable to json. So, no luck for you here.

Do you really need that level of dynamism, though?

Comment: Actually I am creating a concern and passing `if` and `unless` procs in the concern method. the worker will be calling that method recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a wrapping job that may or may not run the proper job for you?

```
class ExecuteAfterIntervalWorkerIfEnabled
  def self.perform(...)
    obj = Object.find(id)
    ExecuteAfterIntervalWorker.perform(...) if obj.enabled?
  end
end
```

Comment: Added example to illustrate

Comment: Actually I am creating a concern and passing if and unless procs in the concern method. the worker will be calling that method recursively. So the method name is dunamic and might not be simple method, it could be conditions

Comment: So, create two wrappers, you want to choose the route (if vs !if) on job creation, but, only care about validity of job on execution.